# Rstudio saves Rscript and updates file but upon opening there is no code

Tags: r, rstudio

all I'm having a bit of a meltdown.

I have just started coding in Rstudio and making some headway but I have found that Rstudio is not actually saving my code in the Rscript files I created. It will update the file modification timestamp when I save but when I close and reopen the Rscript file is empty.

and I'm getting no errors reported to me.

Does anyone have any idea what is going on I can't find any information online?

### i have discovered some new information now. a file will save and remember the contents if there is less than one or 3 lines of interactive code e.g.

```
library(tidyverse) 
    library(tidymodels) 
    library(prospectr)
```

but more than 3 lines of active code  and the file will be blank when reopend
e.g.
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
library(prospectr)

```
    #read spectrum to "spec"
    spec<-read_csv("feildspec_calset.csv")%>%
      mutate(
        soil = parse_factor(soil),
        spike = parse_factor(spike),
        calibration = parse_factor(calibration),
        rep = parse_factor(rep))ter code here
```

I also found it could save several lines of notes e.g.

```
 #fjfjfjfj
#adsjfajfdja
#fjfjfjfj
#adsjfajfdja
#fjfjfjfj
#adsjfajfdja
#fjfjfjfj
#adsjfajfdja
```

but not more than 10 lines of this code.

I suspect it's something to do with the file sizes has anyone experienced a specific problem like this before?

**hear is a break down of what I have been doing using screanshots**

[step one write some code in a new r.script file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXKqS.png)

[step two save file (no longer red text in tab)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72QuA.png)

[step three reopen file to find a blank file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpjqM.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO!  I'm afraid we really need more information before we can help you.

Comment: Is it not saving the .r files in a directory? Or it's saving empty .r files?

Comment: Could you provide screenshots or more description of your problem, e.g. where you're saving your files, how you're saving them, and so on?

Comment: Very odd behaviour. Have you filed this as an issue to RStudio? https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues What version of RStudio are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue now

my university provided me with (RStudio desktop) 1.1456

now that I have installed the RStudio 1.41717

I have found the code that was saved in the Rscript files.

I am very happy now.